# Building numpy from source is affecting other environments as well

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I have two Conda environments named: **machine_learning** and **numpy_dev** I was looking into the codebase of NumPy and installed by source using

```
python setup.py develop
```

But before doing this I had done 
`python setup.py build_ext -i` and then had done `export PYTHONPATH=$PWD` (which I didn't know was not permanent so did `python setup.py develop` later ) which has effectively ruined the python path for all the environments.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the library but as the path is still set, I am unable to set the `PYTHONPATH` for the library to point to default location.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, don't set `PYTHONPATH` globally since it violates the isolation of the environment. If you must set it, have it get set only when the environment you need it in is activated. There will be a nicer way to do this in Conda v4.8, but for now one can add scripts to `envs/yourenv/etc/conda/activate.d` and `envs/yourenv/etc/conda/deactivate.d` to add and remove the path from `PYTHONPATH`, respectively. Details in [the Conda documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables).